The relationship between infinity and periodicity
There is a question:

if
$
f(x) = x\ tan(\frac{\pi}{6}\ e^{sin\ x}), x \in (-\infty, +\infty).
$
then $f(x)$ is:
A. Even function
B. Unbounded function
C. Periodic function
D. Monotonic function

In the answer provided in the book, when proving that $f(x)$ is not a periodic function, it says:

Since $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty$, therefore $f(x)$ is not a periodic function.

I don't quite understand why.

Continuous periodic functions are bounded.

You could also see that while $\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}e^{\sin{x}})$ is periodic, multiplying $x$ makes it lose its periodicity.
